# stop propagation, прекратить обработку нажатия на вложенные элементы

Tags: jquery

Дано:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(".div3").live('click',function(){
  doSomething3();
});
$(".div2").live('click',function(){
  doSomething2();
});
$(".div1").live('click',function(){
  doSomething1();
});
</script>
<div class='div1'>
  <div class='div2'>
    <div class='div3'>
      Some text;
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вопрос следующий: как не дать выполниться doSomething2, doSomething1?
Обычно я решаю это совершенно извратским сочетанием стоппропагейшн и стоп иммидиэт пропагейшн. Какое есть красивое решение?
Решение с использованием проверки глобального массива divClicked[1/2/3] красивым не считать.

P.S. убрать doSomething2 и doSomething1 - тоже не вариант. Мне нужно следить за нажатием на родительские дивы.

Comment: Поправка: doSomething2, doSomething1.
doSomething3 и так не будет выполняться при нажатии на родительский див

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".div__").live('click',function(e){
    doSomething3();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Жуквери сама следит за кроссбраузерностью кода.

Comment: То есть достаточно только одного stopPropagation()?   
Зачем тогда stopImmidiatePropagation()?
Я помню, у меня как-то что-то не получилось вот в таком виде.

Comment: Спасибо, похоже, велосипед уже был изобретен-таки.

Comment: stopImmediatePropagation применяется если на элементе висит несколько обработчиков. Тогда после вызова stopImmediatePropagation другие обработчики не отработают. stopPropagation же предотвращает "всплывание" события по элементам.  
Хотя вот на live [stopImmediatePropagation][1] не сработает, а жаль.

[1]: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/